# Error in semget() Function - Semaphores

Tags: c, operating-system, semaphore

```
semget(key_t key, int nsems, int semflg);
```

When the value of nsems (total number of semaphores) is 4, the function executes successfully, but when the value of nsems is 5, the program terminates with an error "Invalid arguments".

From the internet I have found that if nsems is greater than the limit (i.e. maximum number of semaphores per semaphore set), it returns error.

My question is there any way to remove this error? Can we increase the limit of total semaphores in semaphore set?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: SEMMSL Maximum number of semaphores per semaphore ID.  On Linux systems before version 3.19, the default value for this limit
              was 250.  Since Linux 3.19, the default value is 32,000.  On
              Linux, this limit can be read and modified via the first field
              of /proc/sys/kernel/sem.

Comment: Note that the kernel configuration mechanisms for this vary across platforms.  If you identify which operating system you're working on, you will get more accurate help.    The configuration file to edit on Solaris is different from the one to edit on Mac OS X, and both are probably different from the one to edit on Linux.  You often need to reboot the system after adjusting the limit.  Given the comment by @Mirakurun, you probably aren't using Linux.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I am using linux... to be more precise its ubuntu 15.10, 64 bit...

Comment: Maybe some of: [Ubuntu `sysctl` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/sysctl.8.html), Server Fault [How to set shmall, shmmax, etc](https://serverfault.com/questions/373375/how-to-set-shmall-shmmax-shmni-etc-in-general-and-for-postgresql), [RedHat on Semaphores](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Tuning_and_Optimizing_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_for_Oracle_9i_and_10g_Databases/sect-Oracle_9i_and_10g_Tuning_Guide-Setting_Semaphores-Setting_Semaphore_Parameters.html).